# SSH connection from internet through server1 (on internet) to local server2(not on internet)

Tags: linux, nat, iptables-redirect

I got some pain to solve the following problem and I would appreciate some help.

**I have:**

- Server1 connected to the internet and connected on LAN1 (Debian)
  Public IP: xx.xx.xx.xx
  Private IP on LAN1: 192.168.1.10
- Server2 isolated from internet and connected on LAN1 (Ubuntu)
  Private IP on LAN1: 192.168.1.17

**What I whish to achieve:**

From a remote laptop, establish an SSH connection to Server 2 using:

```
ssh -p1110 login@xx.xx.xx.xx
```

**Where I got so far:**

Server1 can ping Server2 on LAN1 (and opposite)
I can log via ssh on Server1 with my remote laptop using

```
ssh -p 20 login@xx.xx.xx.xx
```

I can log via ssh on Server2 using

```
ssh -p 1110 login@192.168.1.17
```

Server2 ssh config was set to allow 1110 port (and of course service restarted)

From both clear iptables, i set on Server1:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d xx.xx.xx.xx --dport 1110 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.17:1110
```

(Note: that for testing purpose both ufw are disable and set by default to ALLOW Bidirectional connection)

at the stage, i cannot access the server2 from my remote laptop.

Troubleshoot:
So far I try to ensure that at list the ssh session reach the server2

for that I used on server1:

```
sudo tcpdump -i ens1 port 1110
```

and I do can find some traces activity on server1

Same on server2

```
sudo tcpdump -i ens18 port 2201
```

And I also can see some traces at the moment of my remote ssh session try.

So I do think that the request pass by server1 and reach server2

**My theory**

Maybe the iptables rules is not bidirectional ?
Maybe need to do some ipatables setting on server2 as well ?

If you have an idea to help I would appreciate.
Thanks is advance

PS: I cannot only do routing on server level as i have no control on the router

Comment: Copying a comment that OP put below my answer: « I would need port forwarding solution as I used ssh for a simpler test/example ». So don't pay too much attention to ssh, this is really an iptable question. I'm going to update the tags accordingly

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can connect to server1 with ssh, redirecting ports through `iptables` in not the best (secure) way to connect to server2 IMHO.

You did not report it, but from what you write, this single command should theoretically work:

```
ssh -p 20 login@xx.xx.xx.xx ssh -p 1110 login@192.168.1.17
```

This can be translated like this in your configuration file ~/.ssh/config

```
Host server1
    Port 20
    HostName xx.xx.xx.xx
    User login

Host server2
    Port 1100
    HostName 192.168.1.17
    User login
    ProxyCommand ssh server1 -W %h:%p
```

Here `ProxyCommand` tells ssh to first ssh onto server1 before attempting to ssh onto 192.168.1.17:1100

Now you just have to do `ssh server1` to ssh onto server1 and `ssh server2` to ssh onto server2 (and you can remove your iptable rule)

Comment: Yes, but the command does not work in the same way as the config. The command joins two ssh connections, while the config tunnels one via the other. The latter will support scp, sftp and port forwarding, while the former does not.

Comment: actually I would need port forwarding solution as I used ssh for a simpler test/example. The last need would be to forward from server 1 to server 2 multiple different ports for different tools. (mysql/Apache etc..) So I don't think that approach is the good one

Comment: @syncbeam You are right, with this configuration, there is no need for server2's credential on server1. This is a bad wording of mine; my point was to say: "if your firewall allows you to do that, then use this configuration that involves the exact same connections"

Comment: @Waldon mysql? Are you really considering to make your mysql port accessible to everyone on a public IP? If you intend to share *private* services (on 192.168.1.17) to a *private* group, the most secure option is to use ssh, which can forward **securely** whatever you want as long as this is a TCP connection. You only need to make one single port available on the Internet: the ssh port. This is as robust and secure as a VPN. If you want to make a service on 192.168.1.17 publicly accessible, then go with iptables (Apache is OK, but mysql would be an error)

Comment: Xhienne, actually it is for testing purpose. the mysql access is to be set by another remote sever (another country) with some other tool.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot only do routing on server level as i have no control on the router

Eh? But you can apply iptables rules to the hosts - and you are trying to route traffic on the hosts.

> iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d xx.xx.xx.xx --dport 1110 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.17:1110

That gets packets *to* server2, but server2 doesn't send the packets back in the right direction without a route. You'd need to use masquerading or proxying.

The easiest/most flexible solution is to setup ssh_config files for the hosts as chienne suggests.

Comment: I was saying "I cannot only do routing on server level as i have no control on the router" just as a complement of information. I do indeed do nating on the server1.  So how can I redirect the packet back to the good direction ? I have a feeling that the packet on redirect back to server1 but not to the remote laptop.?